# Struts2 BigDecimal Converter is not converting to String

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, bigdecimal, struts2-json-plugin

I have the following code:

**`xwork-conversion.properties`**

```
java.math.BigDecimal=demo.BigDecimalConverter
```

**`BigDecimalConverter.java`**

```
package demo;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.struts2.util.StrutsTypeConverter;

public class BigDecimalConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter{

    @Override
    public Object convertFromString(Map context, String[] values, Class clazz) {
        System.out.println("BigDecimal : Converting from String : " + values[0]);
        return new BigDecimal(values[0]);
    }


    @Override
    public String convertToString(Map context, Object value) {
        String str = ((BigDecimal)value).toPlainString();
        System.out.println("BigDecimal : Converted to String : " + str);
        return str;
    }
}
```

**`TheAction.java`**

```
package demo;

//imports...

public class TheAction extends ActionSupport {
    private BigDecimal bigField;   //with getter and setter

    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**`struts.xml`**

```
<package name="demo"  extends="json-default">
    <action name="processBig" class="demo.TheAction">
        <result type="json"/>
    </action>
</package>
```

**Observation**

When request is submitted with some big decimal say `"12345678901234567890.123456789123456789"`, method `convertFromString` is executed and value is converted to string and prints

```
BigDecimal : Converting from String : 12345678901234567890.123456789123456789
```

But when response is parsed, method `convertToString` is not executed as it does not log expected line on standard output. Struts2 internally converts `BigDecimal` to `String` and following response is returned.

```
{"bigField":12345678901234567890.123456789123456789}
```

When response is received in JavaScript, it becomes `12345678901234567000`, a big loss of value.

---

**Questions:**

- Why `BigDecimalConverter.convertToString` is not being called?
- Is there any other way to achieve this (without defining corresponding `String` field and/or `String` getter)?

Comment: Is 12345678901234567890 instead of 123456789123456789 a typo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

1. `BigDecimalConverter.convertToString` is not being called because it isn't used.

   > Is there any other way to achieve this (without defining corresponding
   >   String field and/or String getter)?
2. No, you can't. JavaScript is a not your language choice or you can use it as string. Means that a limitation of the language you can overcome with something like [`bigdecimal.js`](https://github.com/iriscouch/bigdecimal.js).

Comment: I am already using `bigdecimal.js`. But we first need a string with full value. As shown in the question, `bigField` is not a string, it is interpreted as number in javascript.

Comment: I did not understand the statement `it isn't used`. Because when I call `processBig.action` with some value of `bigField`, it is populated on action with its setter, `execute` method is called, and json response is returned using its `getter` method.

Comment: json response doesn't use a struts converter.

Answer (score 5):

Some possible solutions to resolve it.

**Use a pseudo getter**

```
public String getBigFieldString() {
    return bigField != null ? bigField.toPlainString : null;
}
```

and plugin will serialize it as `bigFieldString:"12345678901234567890.123456789123456789"`. You can also use field's getter to do this.

---

**Change JSON Plugin Code**
Copy `org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter` class from JSON Plugin to your project code. and update `process` method as below. (Be careful while doing this.)

```
package org.apache.struts2.json;
...
class JSONWriter {
...
    private void process(Object object, Method method) throws JSONException {
        this.stack.push(object);

        if (object instanceof Class) {
            this.string(object);
        } else if (object instanceof Boolean) {
            this.bool((Boolean) object);
        } 

        // Begin: Handling of Big Decimal, Keep this code above Handling of Number
        else if (object instanceof BigDecimal) {
            this.string(((BigDecimal)object).toPlainString());
        } 
        // End: Handling of Big Decimal

        else if (object instanceof Number) {
            this.add(object);
        } else if (object instanceof String) {
            this.string(object);
        } else if (object instanceof Character) {
            this.string(object);
        } else if (object instanceof Map) {
            this.map((Map) object, method);
        } else if (object.getClass().isArray()) {
            this.array(object, method);
        } else if (object instanceof Iterable) {
            this.array(((Iterable) object).iterator(), method);
        } else if (object instanceof Date) {
            this.date((Date) object, method);
        } else if (object instanceof Calendar) {
            this.date(((Calendar) object).getTime(), method);
        } else if (object instanceof Locale) {
            this.string(object);
        } else if (object instanceof Enum) {
            this.enumeration((Enum) object);
        } else {
            this.bean(object);
        }

        this.stack.pop();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. The plugin should have handled `BigDecimal` like this.